# AbstractController::ActionNotFound while method_defined? = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, rspec-rails, rails-engines

After upgrading engine in_quotex to Rails 4.2.0 from Rails 3.2.12, `click_button 'Save'` in integration test throws out error:

```
Failure/Error: click_button 'Save'
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'submit' could not be found for InQuotex::QuotesController
```

Here is the spec case:

```
 it "should work for workflow" do
      visit in_quotex.quotes_path
      click_link 'Submit'
      fill_in 'quote_wf_comment', :with => 'this line tests workflow'
      fill_in 'quote_tax', :with => '10.00'
      click_button 'Save'
 ...
  end
```

Something really puzzles us is that in debug, `InQuotex::QuotesController.method_defined?(:submit)` returns `true` which means there is a method `submit` defined in `quotes controller` (the method submit is `include` in `application controller`). The same piece of spec code works fine with Rails 3.2.12. I am wondering what could cause this type of strange error and how to fix it.

in_quotex.gemspec:

```
  s.add_dependency "rails", "~>4.2.0"
  s.add_dependency "jquery-rails"
  s.add_dependency "simple_form"
  s.add_dependency "will_paginate"
  s.add_dependency "database_cleaner"
  s.add_dependency "execjs"
  s.add_dependency 'protected_attributes'
  s.add_dependency "sass-rails", '~>5.0.1'
  s.add_dependency "coffee-rails", '~>4.1.0'   
  s.add_dependency "uglifier"

  s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
  s.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails", "~> 3.2.0"
  s.add_development_dependency "factory_girl_rails", '~>4.5'
  s.add_development_dependency 'capybara'
  s.add_development_dependency 'launchy'   #with capybara
```

Here is the `submit` form header:

```
<%= simple_form_for @workflow_model_object,  :method => :patch, :url =>  eval(@workflow_result_url)  do |f| %>
```

debug value:

```
@workflow_result_url="submit_quote_path"
@workflow_model_object = {InQuotex::Quote}#<InQuotex::Quote:0x632ac48>
```

Backtrace output (v.very long!):

```
 The action 'submit' could not be found for InQuotex::QuotesController
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:132:in `process'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call
      # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:244:in `process_request'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:67:in `post'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:60:in `process'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:35:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:26:in `submit'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/form.rb:75:in `submit'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/node.rb:60:in `click'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:133:in `block in click'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in `synchronize'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:133:in `click'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:37:in `click_button'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:676:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/in_quotex_linke_tests_spec.rb:156:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:177:in `instance_exec'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:177:in `block in run'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `block in run' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.2.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:387:in `execute_with' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:617:in `run_around_example_hooks_for' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `run' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `with_around_example_hooks' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:174:in `run' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:548:in `block in run_examples' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `map' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `run_examples' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:512:in `run' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:513:in `block in run' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:513:in `map' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:513:in `run' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `map' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
      # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526:in `with_suite_hooks' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109:in `block in run_specs' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62:in `report' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke' 
     # c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>' 
     # c:/Ruby200/bin/rspec:23:in `load' 
     # c:/Ruby200/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you please provide backtrace for your error? Need to specify `-b` argument: `rspec -b spec`

Comment: Line #187 in base.rb under action pack, self.class.action_methods does not have the method submit. The method submit is supposedly  'include' in application controller. Here self is InQuotex::QuotesController.